# same line, multiple repeated values stackedbar Highchart jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

in this HighCharts example : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked

basiclly, i'm looking for a way to make it show with different values 1 line, with multiple values wich can be **repeated in the same line** : 
imagine : in apples, joe take 3, jane 2, john 5, joe take again 2, john 5, albert 8 etc.. all in one line 
can this be done using Highcharts ? if not can you please suggest something that does it?
looking forward,
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/f82jm/ ??

Comment: yes, but you see, john and john have not the same colors ;)

Comment: then you give the colors manually like shown here http://jsfiddle.net/f82jm/1/